# grep to extract unique capitalized phrases

Tags: text-processing, grep

The snippet below produces a list of all capitalized words from input text:

```
grep -o '[^ ]*[[:upper:]][^ ]*' book_text.txt > Capitalized_words.txt
```

Now I would like to extract and count the occurrences of unique capitalized phrases of any length.

That is, I'd like a tally of unique strings of space-delimited words sharing initial capitals. A given unique phrase would not include punctuation or a non-capitalized word, so `University of British Columbia` would be two phrases, `University` and `British Columbia`.

Example Input:

```
Harvard archaeologists in Mexico also participated in the International
School of American Archaeology and Ethnology in Mexico City with scholars from
Mexico, Prussia and the United States.
```

Expected Output:

```
1 - Harvard
1 - International School
1 - American Archaeology
1 - Ethnology
1 - Mexico City
2 - Mexico
1 - Prussia
1 - United States
```

Note that in the example, `Mexico` and `Mexico City` are two different unique phrases sharing one word.

Comment: I'd use `sort` and `uniq -c` for that, but first you'll have to construct a regex that actually matches what you want.

Comment: How would you know that "in Mexico City" isn't part of the name of the school (as "in Philadelphia" is in "University of the Sciences in Philadelphia")? "Harvard" is not any capitalized word at the start of a sentence. How would you treat "Archeologists from Harvard in Mexico ..."? If someone was from republic "Trinidad and Tobago", would you want to list that complete name, or would you want to list it as two names? Will the input contain poetry or Twitter posts? Can we assume that the corpus always contain only names and intermediate stop words?

Comment: To answer@they, "Mexico City" isn't part of  "International School of American Archaeology and Ethnology in Mexico City" since the 'in' lacks an initial capital. The idea is to seek only phrases with initial capitals, as in the proposed output

Comment: @user10489, good idea re: uniq. Finding the reg ex for initial capitals separated by spaces is the nub of my question.

Comment: Doing this (collect capitalised adjacent words (ignoring "of" and "and"), count and output) is not a regular expression type of problem. In Perl, it's a SMOP (Simple Matter of Programming) parsing the strings is easy, associative arrays (key=string, value=count), lots of ways to output.

Comment: @waltinator, the goal is not to ignore non-capitalized words in phrases, simply to tally strings of space-delimited words sharing initial capitals. A given unique phrase terminates when non-capitalized word is introduced. Can reg ex not handle arbitrary numbers of capitalized words in this way?

Comment: @they, I agree. It would be semantically useful to tolerate certain non-capitalized words such as 'of'', and 'in', but that's trickier. I've edited the question to reflect your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU `grep` if build with PCRE support:

```
$ grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)(\s+(?1))*' input | sort | uniq -c
      1 American Archaeology
      1 Ethnology
      1 Example Input
      1 Harvard
      1 International School
      2 Mexico
      1 Mexico City
      1 Prussia
      1 United States
```

Or:

```
<input tr -s '[:space:]' '[ *]' |
  grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)(\s+(?1))*' |
  sort |
  uniq -c
```

To first convert all sequences of whitespace characters (including newline) to a single space, so `Example   Input`, `Example Input`, or `Example\nInput` for instance are considered the same.

Note that `-w` is not for *whitespace delimited* words, the word boundaries are between word and non word characters (word characters being alnums and underscore). You do say you want  *space-delimited words*, but that's in contradiction with expecting `United States` instead of `United States.`  or `Mexico` instead of `Mexico, Prussia` in your input.

Also note that `[^ ]*[[:upper:]][^ ]*` would match on whitespace delimited words that *contain* at least one uppercase letter, but that's not necessarily at the start. For instance it would match on `fooBar` or `0xAB+12`. You'd need `(?<!\S)\p{Lu}\S*` for a whitespace delimited word that starts with an uppercase letter.

```
$ grep -Po '(?<!\S)(\p{Lu}\S*)(\s+(?1))*' input | sort | uniq -c
      1 American Archaeology
      1 Ethnology
      1 Example Input:
      1 International School
      1 Mexico
      1 Mexico City
      1 Mexico, Prussia
      1 United States."
```

(`Harvard` missing because I have the whole line `Example Input: "Havard ..."` in `input` so the whitespace-delimited word is `"Harvard` which doesn't start with an uppercase letter).

You can also throw in some `in`s and `of`s in the middle with:

```
$ grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)((\s+(in|of))?\s+(?1))*' input | sort | uniq -c
      1 Ethnology in Mexico City
      1 Example Input
      1 Harvard
      1 International School of American Archaeology
      2 Mexico
      1 Prussia
      1 United States
```

If dealing with non-English text, you may also want to replace `\w` with `((?=\w)\X)`, that is instead of *word character*, match on a *grapheme cluster that starts with a word character*.

```
$ echo $'Universidad Nacional Auto\u0301noma de Me\u0301xico' |
  grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)((\s+(in|of|de))?\s+(?1))*' | sort | uniq -c
      1 Me
      1 Universidad Nacional Auto
$ echo $'Universidad Nacional Auto\u0301noma de Me\u0301xico' |
  grep -Pow '((?=\p{Lu})\X((?=\w)\X)*)((\s+(in|of|de))?\s+(?1))*' |
  sort | uniq -c
      1 Universidad Nacional Autónoma de México
```

That that would still match on the `Bar` in `$'foo\u0301Bar'`.

You may also need to refine what constitutes a word character / grapheme and/or what the separators are to cover for names such as *Suzy's Kitchen*, *O'Brian Primary School*, *Lycée Jean-Paul Sartre*, etc.

Putting it all those together, we could end-up with:

```
first_grapheme='(?: (?= \p{Lu} ) \X )'
word_character="[\w'-]"
 word_grapheme="(?: (?= $word_character ) \X )"
          word="$first_grapheme $word_grapheme *"
     separator='(?: [ ] (?: in | on | of | de | en ) )? [ ]'

<input tr -s '[:space:]' '[ *]' |
  grep -Po "(?x) (?<! \pM | $word_character ) $word (?: $separator $word ) *" |
  sort |
  uniq -c
```

Comment: It would be a nice touch to catch postfixes for proper names (jr., sr., iii) as in:

echo 'She kneels at the feet of her husband, the powerful, long-lived ruler Itzamnaaj Bahlam iii, who holds a torch.' | grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)((\s+(in|of|de))?\s+(?1))*' | sort | uniq -c

returns:
1 Itzamnaaj Bahlam
1 She

Even better would be:
1 Itzamnaaj Bahlam iii
1 She

Comment: Thank you @Stéphane Chazelas for your excellent, clearly explained, detailed answer. I also appreciate your notes about non-English text, which of course is crucial.

Comment: A name like K’ahk’ Tiliw Chan Yopaat fails here, since [K’ahk’] ends with an apostrophe:

echo 'K’ahk’ Tiliw Chan Yopaat' | grep -Pow '(\p{Lu}\w*)((\s+(in|of|de))?\s+(?1))*' | sort | uniq -c

Comment: Using a Fish shell on Arch the non-English characters here are not captured: "echo 'Madrid’s Museo de América' | grep -Pow '((?=\p{Lu})\X((?=\w)\X)*)((\s+(in|of|de))?\s+(?1))*' | sort | uniq -c" returns: 1 Madrid, 1 Museo de Am.

It would be nice to return:
Madrid’s Museo de América

Comment: I see now that it would be useful to allow carriage returns between words in a capitalized phrases, e.g. : "the Southwest Museum in Los/nAngeles, founded by Charles Lummis in 1907" should return "Southwest Museum in Los Angeles"

Comment: @KevinCain, line delimiter on Unix is the newline character (aka NL, linefeed, LF, \n), not carriage return (aka CR \r). Both LF and CR are matched by `tr`'s `[:space:]` or perl's `\s` though.

Comment: If `América` is broken at `Am` for you, that suggests that `é` is the pre-composed form (single character U+00E9) instead of `e` followed by the combining acute accent (U+0301), and that you've go a locale problem in that your terminal encodes `é` in one charset but the locale either doesn't have that character or expects it in a different encoding. For instance, if `printf é | od -An -vtx1` outputs c3 a9 (the UTF-8 encoding of U+00E9) but `local charmap` doesn't output UTF-8, your `$LANG` or `$LC_*` variables are not set properly. That or grep/pcre were built without i18n support.

Comment: I can confirm UTF-8 output, and that my $LANG is set to en_US.UTF-8. We can force UTF in PCRE via '--enable-utf'.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -e '.subst(",", " and ", :g).subst(".", " ", :g).comb(/ <( [ <:Lu> <:Ll>+ \h+ ]+ )> <:Ll>* /).map(*.trim-trailing).Bag.antipairs.join("\n").say for lines();'
```

Sample Input:

```
Harvard archaeologists in Mexico also participated in the International School of American Archaeology and Ethnology in Mexico City with scholars from Mexico, Prussia and the United States.
```

Sample Output (final):

```
1   Ethnology
1   Prussia
2   Mexico
1   American Archaeology
1   Harvard
1   Mexico City
1   International School
1   United States
```

Interesting question, and I've decided to tackle it with Raku because it is considered to have a rather advanced regex engine (more advanced than PCRE, according to the references at the bottom).

We can begin by breaking down the Raku code into three main sections. The `comb` section uses a regex matcher to break text input into desired elements. Many of the symbols may be familiar to you already (or familiar in concept). As an example, capture markers in Raku are `<(…)>`. The `comb` section alone returns 8/9 expected values, although one is only partially returned.

```
raku -e '.comb(/ <( [ <:Lu> <:Ll>+ \h+ ]+ )> <:Ll>* /).join("\n").say for lines();'
```

Sample Output (attempt #1):

```
Harvard 
Mexico 
International School 
American Archaeology 
Ethnology 
Mexico City 
Prussia 
United
```

We see immediately that something must be done about punctuation, because the value `Mexico,` and partial-value `States.` are both left behind. Second attempt:

```
raku -e '.subst(",", " and ", :g).subst(".", " ", :g).comb(/ <( [ <:Lu> <:Ll>+ \h+ ]+ )> <:Ll>* /).join("\n").say for lines();'
```

Sample Output (attempt #2):

```
Harvard 
Mexico 
International School 
American Archaeology 
Ethnology 
Mexico City 
Mexico 
Prussia 
United States
```

Above returns 9/9 expected values. In the end I decided to replace `,` commas with `and`, and to replace `.` periods with   spaces. (You'll have to decide the best course of action for your texts).

To achieve the final results at top, the calls `.map(*.trim-trailing).Bag.antipairs` were interposed in the code, which produces the desired result.

https://slides.yowconference.com/yowwest2015/Conway-EverythingYouKnowAboutRegexesIsWrong.pdf
https://youtu.be/ubvSjW6Nyqk
https://raku.org